# Why my if condition isn't working with select box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my code, I am trying to make  a code in which I want to get value of select box and add value accordingly but my code is getting a bunch of errors. Can anyone please help me. In code i just want to add 1 to selectbox value. E.g: If i pressed on S and add then 1 should be added to S Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("issue").value;
  var is1 = 0;
  var is2 = 0;
  var is3 = 0;
  if (x == document.getElementById("issue").value) {
    is1 = 1;
  } else if (x == document.getElementById("issue").value) {
    is2 = 1;
  } else if (x == document.getElementById("issue").value) {
    is3 = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
Enter issue code:
<select name="issue" id="issue">
  <option value="i1">S</option>
  <option value="i2">W</option>
  <option value="i3">T</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What errors, on what lines? What have you done to try to understand them / find them in the code? What is the code supposed to do? Also, just logically, it doesn't make sense to put the value of `document.getElementById("issue").value` in `x` (near the top) and then later do `if (x == document.getElementById("issue").value)` -- that's going to be true, you just put that same value in `x`. (Then doing it again in an `else if`...) Also, you're assigning values to local variables but then not using the values in those local variables for anything.

Comment: I simply want to add one number to selectbox value. E.g: If i pressed on S and add then 1 should be added to S

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you have understood want i want to do then can you help me?

Comment: @SugamjeetKaur Means when you select `S` and click add, option `S` should change to `S1`, is that what you want?

Comment: Click add and then 1 should be added to option s

Comment: Simple thing that i want

Comment: But code isn't working

Comment: What do you mean by 1 should be added to option `s`, do you want to store somewhere how many times each option has been clicked?

Comment: How do you expect your option labels to change without setting them? You are only setting the variables `is1`, `is2` and `is3`.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Yes

Comment: @WaisKamal So can you improve me?

Comment: Read about `<select>` elements and how to change the value of their options. You have to show an attempt before someone here helps.

Comment: I have made so many attempts. Read about select on w3schools etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create three variables and update their count based on the selected option.

```js
let is1 = 0, is2 = 0, is3 = 0

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("issue").value;
  if (x === "i1") is1++
  else if (x === "i2") is2++
  else if (x === "i3") is3++
  
  document.getElementById("results").innerText=`Option S: ${is1}\nOption W: ${is2}\nOption T: ${is3}`
}
```

```html
Enter issue code:
<select name="issue" id="issue">
  <option value="i1">S</option>
  <option value="i2">W</option>
  <option value="i3">T</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: And how to do it on website?

Comment: @SugamjeetKaur I didn't get? Which website? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Like index.html i have opened on browser i want to show value on that

Comment: Your answer is correct. Just please tell me how to show the output on browser

Comment: You can create some DOM node and modify the content of that node, If its not clear I will update my answer.

Comment: It would be great pleasure for me

Comment: @SugamjeetKaur I've updated my answer, please check!